# PHP - How to send emails to address on MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I send emails to all emails on my database? E.g. here is my format of MYSQL.

MYSQL -- Table = users --- column = email. I need to send emails to everyone of the email on column "email".

Comment: how many rows (read emails) you have to send an email to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Simple ready to use PHP script for sending mail from mysql data**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  sendMail($row[0]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);

function sendMail($to){
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: After mytable theres "email".

Comment: mytable is your table name, email is your column of email , you can replace by your name.

Comment: :O You scripted for free~! :)

Comment: There we go :) hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to pull data from MySQL? if so, you should just execute the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function for each row.

Answer (score 0):

The code that JapanPro suggested is great! However, I have read over the internet about doing this. If there is loads of emails to be sent it will take a long time and possible slow down your server and clog it up. I would recommend doing it in intervals. So like in sets of 10 or 20.

This is only based on the information I have read. And I can se where they are coming from.